# set font for multiple paragraphs in makecell

Tags: fontsize, makecell

I can set a common font for multiple paragraphs as for par 2 and par 3 in this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
par 1

{
\tiny
par 2\\
par 3
}

par 4
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately this nice feature is disrupted in `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  A & \makecell{\tiny par 2\\par3}\\
  C & D
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the output font size got attributed to par 2 and not to par 3.

[image]

`\makecell` is used to enable multi paragraph content in a table cell.

How to fix?

Comment: I would change `\makecell{\tiny par 2\\par3}` to `\makecell{\tiny par 2\\ \tiny par3}`.

Comment: @Jon Imagine I have 10 such paragraphs in an already complicated table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small change:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  A & \tiny\makecell{par 2\\par 3\\par 4\\par 5}\\
  C & D
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]